# Install.sh asking for password in driver installation

Tags: raspbian, driver

I am trying to install driver for wifi adapter on my headless Rpi(I am a complete newbie), Whilst trying to install in LXterminal it asks for password, I can't figure out which password its asking, Since the only password I ever used with pi is the default password (raspberry )which I use to login through ssh. I haven't ever used any password for anything (I just brought pi couple of weeks ago). So anyone has idea what the password might be asking.

PS: Any information on installing drivers will be beneficial.

I am using raspbean

Thank you

**Edit1**

Device I am using : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSnn5.png

```
'dmesg' 
     new high-speed USB device number 5 using swc_otg
     New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
     New USB device strings:Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
     Product: 802.11 n WLAN
     Manufacturer: MediaTek
     SerialNumber:1.0
```

`lsusb`

```
ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp
```

PS: Since I just joined community I can't post more than 2 links so I've created a file on google drive which contains links to various snapshots (Related to this problem). I can add links to it so that it facilitates the problem solving.
here's the link to file (which contains some links already, others can be added if need be).
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxuPEVNjHFQkTFRXajRDOFZiQ0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why?  What wifi device are you trying to get to work?  When you insert the dongle in a USB port use the dmesg command.  What device numbers are reported?  Mine shows "New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601" which I thought was the same as yours.  What numbers are given by your dongle?

Answer (score 1):

There are two known ways of getting the device with USB id idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601 to work on the Raspberry Pi.

I'm only going to mention the preferred way here.

To use that device you need a recent kernel and a binary blob.

To get a recent kernel on Rasbian issue the command

```
sudo rpi-update # say Y if prompted to confirm
```

To get the binary blob and install it in the correct place cut&paste the following command:

```
sudo wget https://github.com/porjo/mt7601/raw/master/src/mcu/bin/MT7601.bin -O /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin
```

Then reboot.

The dongle should then work.