# Wifi dongle - wlan not listed

Tags: raspbian

I am using MediaTek 7610 wifi dongle , the dongle is getting detected by the rasbian but when I try ifconfig command , the wlan interface is not listed .I have attached the screen shot of the configs. I hope it helps. If any more details are required please do let me know. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your /etc/network/interfaces contain?

Comment: @joan I have added the contents of interfaces file.

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste the actual text into the question, in lieu of photographs/screenshots? It makes it easier to search for the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using the same dongle without problems.

I did **two** things.

1. sudo rpi-update
2. sudo wget
   https://github.com/porjo/mt7601/raw/master/src/mcu/bin/MT7601.bin -O
   /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin

lssub reports

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
```

iwconfig reports

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"myessid"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:16:41:18:9D:1F   
          Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1233   Missed beacon:0
```

dmesg reports

```
[   15.869703] usb 1-1.5: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[   15.972604] mt7601u 1-1.5:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
[   15.982453] mt7601u 1-1.5:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
[   16.397793] mt7601u 1-1.5:1.0: Warning: unsupported EEPROM version 0d
[   16.397834] mt7601u 1-1.5:1.0: EEPROM ver:0d fae:00
[   16.692923] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[   16.698545] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
```

uname -a reports

```
Linux harry 4.1.6+ #810 PREEMPT Tue Aug 18 15:19:58 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: except one difference , I am using Linux Raspberry pi 4.1.7-v7+  arm7l  , does that require any changes?  because I tried exactly the same steps but it still didn't get listed.

Comment: It started working :) , earlier I did wget and then rpi-update but this time I first did rpi-update and then did wget from GitHub as suggested by you . Not sure what difference it made , it started working now . Thanks.

Comment: @jaycyborg I should point out that the MT7601 driver can crash under heavy network load on the Pi2. I believe the cause has been identified and a fix is known.  I don't know how long the fix will take to appear in the kernel.  This only affects the multi-core Pi2.

Comment: Oops that's sad .. Thanks for letting me know , I will keep an eye on that and will update once the fix is available .

Comment: @jaycyborg The issue https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1131 has a fix in the September 17th 2015 kernel release.  So if you do another sudo rpi-update it may be fixed.

Comment: @jaycyborg My initial tests suggest the problem has been fixed.

Comment: I did run rip-update today .So I guess that is fixed  :)

Comment: That file doesn't exist anymore (and so repo)

Comment: @ruX The driver has been part of mainstream Linux for a year or so now, so you shouldn't need the file anymore.

Comment: @joan not really. I've just updated rpi zero to 4.9 and all software. Yes, module is there but there is a problem with EEPROM version mismatch. I'm not sure is these issues are related

Comment: @ruX Can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a wifi driver loaded.

To list *available* interfaces, you should use:

```
ifconfig -a
  - OR -
ip link
```

Just plain `ifconfig` lists only interfaces which are in an "up" state, which by default wifi probably is not, particularly if ethernet is already connected.

Comment: tried ifconfig -a , posted the contents for your reference.

Comment: Seems the driver does not work then -- have a look at this answer to do with the same chipset: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36377/5538

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply.The current MT7601 binary was part of the updated raspbian kernel, it was not installed manually . Do you still want me to try with the blob on github as suggested by that post?

Comment: Up to you.  I haven't used that chip, I just remembered the question from the other day.  The [entry point to that git repo](https://github.com/porjo/mt7601) says it is obsolete as of kernel 4.2, but I don't think Rasbian is on 4.2 yet; you can check with `uname -r`.

Comment: I tried , still same result :( not getting listed but getting detected and listed when using command lsusb. No issues with the dongle , I have tried it on my Mac  it works perfectly. So I guess it must be with the driver.

Comment: The problem with linux and drivers is manufacturers generally do not supply them, so it is up to someone else to do the reverse engineering.   For that reason it is best to check before you buy, which is complicated by the fact that the box usually doesn't say which chipset is used, and it is possible for the exact same brand and model number of adapter to exist in indistinguishable versions, using *different* chipsets -- which you won't find out until you plug it in, but if you bought it somewhere that will take it back within a few days no questions asked, that's okay.

Comment: In any case, doing a more than cursory job of checking is a good idea, and avoid anything with sketchy details such as this (requires a special download).   There is [this unofficial "verified peripherals" page](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals) and while we don't allow shopping recommendation questions ("Which adapter should I buy?") we do allow questions such as "Will this particular adapter work?"

Comment: yep, thats right. The package didn't mention anything about the chipset used. I figured it out form the devices information on Mac. If this dongle doesnt work  then , I have to get another wifi dongle that works with raspbian. Thanks for your efforts :) .

Comment: USB chips have unique manufacturer/model identifiers (which are not the same as the brand and model of the adapter) listed by `lsusb` (a driver is not required for this, as that's how a driver is selected).  In this case it's `148f` (Ralink) and `7601`.  This ID is what you want to investigate (they're in fact listed in the kernel driver sources so drivers can be appropriately paired, although finding them is not always easy and as we see in this case, is not a guarantee).   Without plugging one in, you can usually get the ID by googling the adapter (and hope it is always the same).

Comment: The stack overflow post that you shared was exactly the same as shared by Joan , except the steps were in reverse order , first rip-update and then wget , It started working now . Thanks for your efforts in helping me .